# Returning multiple objects and using them as arguments

Tags: python, function, functional-programming, return, arguments

I have a function which goes something like this:

```
def do_something(lis):
    do something
    return lis[0], lis[1]
```

and another function which needs to take those two return objects as arguments:

```
def other_function(arg1, arg2):
    pass
```

I have tried:

```
other_function(do_something(lis))
```

but incurred this error:

> TypeError: other_function() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg2'

Comment: show `other_function` function declaration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to unpack those arguments when calling `other_function`.

```
other_function(*do_something(lis))
```

Based on the error message, it looks like your other function is defined (and should be defined as)

```
def other_function(arg1, arg2):
    pass
```

So, when you return from `do_something`, you are actually returning a tuple containing `(lis[0], lis[1])`. So when you originally called `other_function`, you passing a single tuple, when your `other_function` was still expecting a second argument.

You can see this if you break it down a bit further. Below is a breakdown of how the returns look like when handled differently, a reproduction of your error and a demo of the solution:

Returning in to a single variable will return a tuple of the result:

```
>>> def foo():
...     lis = range(10)
...     return lis[1], lis[2]
...
>>> result = foo()
>>> result
(1, 2)
```

Returning in to two variables, unpacks in to each var:

```
>>> res1, res2 = foo()
>>> res1
1
>>> res2
2
```

Trying to call other_function with `result` which now only holds a tuple of your result:

```
>>> def other_function(arg1, arg2):
...     print(arg1, arg2)
...
>>> other_function(result)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: other_function() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg2'
```

Calling other_function with `res1`, `res2` that holds each value of the return from `foo`:

```
>>> other_function(res1, res2)
1 2
```

Using `result` (your tuple result) and unpacking in your function call to `other_function`:

```
>>> other_function(*result)
1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
other_function(*do_something(list))
```

The `*` char will expand the `tuple` returned by `do_something`.

Your `do_something` function is actually returning a `tuple` which contains several values but **is** only one value itself.

See [the doc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) for more details.